# Return Final List from Filtered Observable

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an

```
Observable<List<ObjectModel>>
```

and I need the list returned to be Immutable, however for some reason when applying the below filter it is not. Can someone tell me how to preserve Immutability? thanks!

```
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(Observable::from).filter(objectModel -> {
                return objectModel.isEnabled();
            }).toList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toList` operator emits a mutable `List` as you've noted (`java.util.ArrayList`). Just map it to the immutable list type of your choice. For example:

```
obs.toList()
   .map(Collections::unmodifiableList);
```

or using guava:

```
obs.toList()
   .map(ImmutableList::copyOf);
```

Answer (score 1):

so the answer as to why i was experiencing my issues is explained here:

http://www.javacreed.com/modifying-an-unmodifiable-list/

adding

```
.map(Collections::unmodifiableList)`
```

fixed it